# Different file size when encrypting with Bouncy Castle (In Java) and GPG4Win

Tags: java, encryption, size, rsa, bouncycastle

Here is the problem:
I use Bouncy Castle (Java) library to encrypt a file, but the size of encrypted file that I get is much bigger than when I use other utilities (i.e. GPG4Win, FileAssurity).
The encrypted file size that these utilities generate are very small comparing to what my code generates.

I am wondering if there are different ways of encrypting when using RSA public keys as opposed DSA ones.

Additional info:

Public Key Certificate type: 2,047-bit RSA

The code that I use to encrypt a data file (file is read and passed as byte array):

```
private static byte[] encrypt(byte[] clearData, PGPPublicKey encKey, boolean withIntegrityCheck, boolean armor) 
    throws IOException, PGPException, NoSuchProviderException {

    ByteArrayOutputStream encOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    OutputStream out = encOut;
    if(armor) {
        out = new ArmoredOutputStream(out);
    }

    ByteArrayOutputStream bOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    PGPLiteralDataGenerator lData = new PGPLiteralDataGenerator();

    OutputStream pOut = lData.open(bOut/*cos*/, // the compressed output stream
        PGPLiteralData.BINARY, PGPLiteralData.CONSOLE, // "filename" to store (if provided)
        clearData.length, // length of clear data
        new Date() // current time
        );
    pOut.write(clearData);

    PGPEncryptedDataGenerator cPk = new PGPEncryptedDataGenerator(PGPEncryptedData.CAST5, withIntegrityCheck, new SecureRandom(), C_BC_PROVIDER_NAME);
    cPk.addMethod(encKey);

    byte[] bytes = bOut.toByteArray();
    bOut.close();

    OutputStream cOut = cPk.open(out, bytes.length);

    cOut.write(bytes); 

    cOut.close();
    out.close();
    return encOut.toByteArray();
} // encrypt
```

Comment: You are probably creating a detached signature and leaving the original file intact with other utilities.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on your comment?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your question? You did not provide any example of what is the real difference. I bothered to look at your code second time and i see that it is also possible that your code outputs armored text, which will be roughly twice the size of binary data.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPCompressedDataGenerator;
```